# Creality CR Touch not precise enough

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling, bltouch, creality

I have the problem that the bed auto level functionality is working but not precise enough so that the first layer doesn't stick everywhere and the "paper sheet check" for each corner gives different results.

I have a Creality Ender 3 V2 with [CR Touch](https://www.creality3dofficial.com/products/creality-cr-touch) auto level sensor and Marlin firmware (Marlin bugfix-JyersUI v2.0.1 (Nov  5 2021 21:19:16)).

I do the bed auto level either via G-code `G29` in each print-file it self or via OctoPrint Bed Visualizer:

```
M140 S60 ; starting by heating the bed for nominal mesh accuracy
M117 Homing all axes ; send message to printer display
G28      ; home all axes
M420 S0  ; Turning off bed leveling while probing, if firmware is set
         ; to restore after G28
M117 Heating the bed ; send message to printer display
M190 S60 ; waiting until the bed is fully warmed up
M300 S1000 P500 ; chirp to indicate bed mesh levels is initializing
M117 Creating the bed mesh levels ; send message to printer display
M155 S30 ; reduce temperature reporting rate to reduce output pollution
@BEDLEVELVISUALIZER ; tell the plugin to watch for reported mesh
G29 T      ; run bilinear probing
M155 S3  ; reset temperature reporting
M140 S0 ; cooling down the bed
M500 ; store mesh in EEPROM
M300 S440 P200 ; make calibration completed tones
M300 S660 P250
M300 S880 P300
M117 Bed mesh levels completed ; send message to printer display
```

I added `M420 S1` into all my G-code print files.
I checked that the auto leveling is active by sending single commands via terminal to the printer:
After Homing Z the Z value is as expected: 0 (zero).
After activating auto level compensation with `M420 S1` it stays zero. Then I move the printer into a corner with `G0 x120 y120 z1 F5000` followed by `G0 Z0`.
Then `M114` shows `Recv: X:120.00 Y:120.00 Z:0.00 E:32.24 Count X:9600 Y:9600 Z:-7"`. The `Z: -7`  shows me that auto leveling is doing something.
But when I check in the corner the "paper sheet check" shows different results in the corner than in the center (where I calibrated the Z-offset with the "paper sheet check").
Also the bed visualizer doesn't show the same results when I run it twice in sequence (the standard deviation of the sensor is supposed to be [0.001 mm](https://www.creality3dofficial.com/blogs/unboxing-product-comparison/creality-bl-touch-firmware)):

First run:

[image: First run]

Second run:

[image: Second run]

`M48 P10` on my machine results in

```
Send: M48 P10
Recv: M48 Z-Probe Repeatability Test
[...]
Recv: Finished!
Recv: Mean: -0.005500 Min: -0.007 Max: -0.003 Range: 0.005
Recv: Standard Deviation: 0.001204
```

Which looks similar, I guess? (Open question: Does my firmware even have the `AUTO_BED_LEVELING_UBL` option? How can I find out?)

I could not feed any wiggle room on any axis of my printer, or the nozzle or the CR touch sensor.

So my question is: What could be wrong with my printer? I assume the BL/CR touch sensor works for other people as expected.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a separate question on `AUTO_BED_LEVELING_UBL` so that it can be answered separately? E.g. to answer that we require more info how you got the firmware or whether you compiled it yourself. The answer is in the configuration file, as long as it is unknown what configuration file is used, it cannot be answered.

Comment: Since I couldn't find out which options are active for my image I downloaded one with UBL Leveling explicitly active (https://github.com/Jyers/Marlin/releases/tag/v2.0.1) and after first tests it is better now.  The other binary I used before was also downloaded from there : https://github.com/Jyers/Marlin/releases/download/v2.0.1/E3V2-BLTouch-5x5-v4.2.2-v2.0.1.bin

Comment: I found now out which leveling method is used: `AUTO_BED_LEVELING_BILINEAR`